# Help for redirect all default page magento to 404 or homepage with .htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, htaccess

I'am on **magento 1.9.3.8**, i know it would be time for me to go on **magento 2...**

So i have this url by default in magento :

```
downloader/
catalogsearch/advanced/
catalog/seo_sitemap/product/
catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
rss/catalog/notifystock/
rss/order/new/
index.phprss/catalog/notifystock/
customer-service/
sales/guest/form/
privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode/
```

How i can redirect this url with .htaccess to my **home page or 404 ?**

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

add these to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Googlebot|bingbot|Yahoo|Yandex|rogerbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(catalogsearch/advanced|catalog/seo_sitemap/product|catalog/seo_sitemap/category|catalog/seo_sitemap/category|rss/catalog/notifystock|downloader|catalog/product_compare|rss/order/new|index.phprss/catalog/notifystock|customer-service|sales/guest/form|privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode)/
RewriteRule .* - [G]
```